# How to display a checkbox based on a conditon in Alpaca?

Tags: alpacajs

I need to display a checkbox only if a particular condition is true.
For example in the below code the method isGame_Started() is true then only the checkbox should be displayed. I did not find any thing relevant in the Alpaca documentation

```
    "fields": {
    "isGame_Over?": {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "rightLabel": "Is Game Over ?",
      "condition" : isGame_Started() ? "true" : "false"
    }
```

}

I need some code in place of the "condition" that can do the work I need.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can find the solution in the [documentation](http://www.alpacajs.org/docs/fields/checkbox.html), you should use options > hidden instead of condition, there's no condition properties in options configuration. You can use the `hidden` attribute and assigne a function to it like this `"hidden": isGame_Started()` where `isGame_Started()` can return true or false depends on your logic.

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vert3x/8waj7gdk/) for this.
You can change `isGame_Started` logic and test.

Comment: @Roshni is it what you're looking for? if so can you please accept the answer? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work